# android actionbar google tutorial

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar

i have done the android action bar google tutorial,
but this is what i got:

[image]

the action setting button does not appear, and when the search button pressed nothing happens.
can any one tell me what is wrong with the code?

here is the files code..

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.actionbar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public void openSearch(){

    System.out.println("TEST SEARCH");

}
public void openSettings(){

    System.out.println("TEST SETTINGS");

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

**MainActivityActions.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      yourapp:showAsAction="always"  />

<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.actionbar"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.actionbar.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: btw you should not use System.out.println but Log.d("tag", "msg") instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are using AppCompat.

When using appCompat you need to specify more things in the menu xml

Exemple:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
          yourapp:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"   />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        yourapp:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Note:
For the search item it's missing the bold part:
**yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"**
yourapp:showAsAction="always|**collapseActionView**"

and the settings item it's missing the following bold part:
**yourapp**:showAsAction="never"

the actionViewClass means it's going to use the SearchView with the dropdown "window"

you can also use collapseActionView to make the search item expand and collapse if you are not using the searchView

See this [video](https://plus.google.com/+ChrisBanes/posts/WhFZ4MVGjSg) from Chris Banes about appcompat

Comment: ok thank you, but why is my code does not work??

    public void openSearch(){
    System.out.println("TEST SEARCH"); } 
    public void openSettings(){ 
    System.out.println("TEST SETTINGS"); } 


and when i set settings to yourapp:showAsAction="never" it desappear again

Comment: sorry I thought you wanted the settings in the overflow menu (on samsung phone you can press the physical menu button). "never" goes in overflow, "ifRoom" displays it in the actionbar

Comment: from your comments: <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->

Comment: ooh ok realy thank you friend :))) the comment is my mistake just copy and pasted :P

Comment: then you can mark the answer as accepted if you think its sufficient or you can +1 if it only helped

Comment: cant +1 i need 15 rep sry :(( how to close??

Answer (score 1):

In your MainActivityActions.xml, change the `android:showAsAction="never"` under the settings to "always"

Comment: done that didn't help :( but then i added the 
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          yourapp:showAsAction="always"  /> and the setting button appear now, but still after pressing the button nothing happens